# Comparing nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, one of the form:

```
[a1, b1, [[c1, d1, e1], [f1, g1, h1], etc, etc], etc]
```

and the other, a dictionary, whose entries are in the form:

`[[a2, b2, c2], [d2, e2, f2], etc, etc]`.

I need to compare the first entries of those two sub lists there and find any which are the same, and any in the first which don't appear at all in the second.

Foe example, if `c1 = d2`, I'd want to know, and if `f1` isn't equal to either `a2` or `d2`, I'd want to know that.

Anyway, I'm having a bit of trouble implementing this properly, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

(I'm not sure how clear the list formats are to understand, sorry if they're still confusing)

CODE SAMPLE:

```
for row in range(0, len(command[2])):

    counter = 0

    for nodeRows in range(0, len(nodeTable[command[0]])):

        if nodeTable[command[0]][nodeRows][0] == command[2][row][0]:

            if ((command[2][row][2]) + 1) < nodeTable[command[0]][nodeRows][2]:

                counter += 1

                newrow = command[2][row]
                newrow[1] = command[1]
                newrow[2] = newrow[2] + 1

                nodeTable[command[0]][nodeRows] = newrow

                change = 'true'
```

I imagine this doesn't help. The code is a bit monolithic (that's why I didn't post it initially). But I'm basically trying to compare two values. The first values of the items from the list in the 3rd position of another list and the first values of the items from the lists contained in another list.

Um...sorry. I have tried making the code simpler, but it's a bit complicated.

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you've tried, because what you have is confusing as hell.

Comment: @Incredidave, until you can post your code we're going to temporarily downgrade you to Justokaydave.

Comment: Okay, I'll post some. This might get even more confusing though, the code is....loopful.

Comment: What is 2? Can we start with some descriptive symbols for the magic indexes? ...might be able to help better.

Comment: Ok, Incredi- status restored.  I wouldn't describe it as "loopful" so much as "interestingly nested."  You could consider making it easier for the next person (likely you!) to understand by giving a name to expressions like `command[2][row][2]) + 1)` -- e.g. "`def command_frobnosticate(cmd, row): return cmd[2][row][2]`".  Or better still, leverage another data structure like a new `class` or `namedtuple`.

Comment: Well, the names aren't too bad with respect to the actual code. For example, command is the current active command from a list of commands.
I guess the problem is using the normal python looping and comparison functions but looping through the level I don't want to compare.

Comment: @Incredidave: alright, you just added a new variable to the problem. You need to be a little more descriptive of the problem - specifically what is this mystic list of commands? what is its function? where does it come from?

Comment: @Incredidave: the first list is a nested list? the second iterable is a dictionary? or is it also an ordered iterable? because you speak of list and then for the second data-structure from a dict!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm  not sure I understand correctly your problem but I'll give it a try.
I guess you need to compare only the first element of every
sublist of 3 elements.

So first I separate all the first elements, then make the comprarisson.

Here is the code with some [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) so you can check if it does what you
are asking:

```
def compare(l0, l1):
    """
    >>> l0 = [1, 2, [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]], 3]
    >>> l1 = [[11, 21, 31], [41, 51, 61], [71, 81, 91]]
    >>> compare(l0, l1)
    ([], [10, 40, 70])

    >>> l0 = [1, 2, [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]], 3]
    >>> l1 = [[10, 21, 31], [41, 51, 61], [71, 81, 91]]
    >>> compare(l0, l1)
    ([10], [40, 70])

    >>> l0 = [1, 2, [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]], 3]
    >>> l1 = [[10, 21, 31], [40, 51, 61], [70, 81, 91]]
    >>> compare(l0, l1)
    ([10, 40, 70], [])
    """
    first_entries_l0 = [x[0] for x in l0[2]]
    first_entries_l1 = [x[0] for x in l1]

    equals = [x for x in first_entries_l0 if x in first_entries_l1]
    unique = [x for x in first_entries_l0 if x not in first_entries_l1]

    return equals, unique
```

To test the code just copy it to a file 'code.py' and run it with:

```
python -m doctest code.py
```

You could make it more efficient using sets and looping only once but I'm not even sure this solves your problem so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, but I believe you may have hit upon the right answer. Just tried creating the list in my code and it seems to do exactly what I want. Thank you very much (I know the code wasn't the easiest to use, annoyingly enough, that's about the most helpful format I can get it in).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: transform your current datastructure to a proper one. Presumably the inputs are be defined by yourself, so you should not write better code to deal with ugly structures, but improve the structures. If you are writing against a bad API, map the API to a useful structure.

You will have to post the whole code to get a proper answer, because the problem is in the definitions. I guess you will have to refactor the whole module and start again, because this is simply bad code.

Some ideas: could command be a tree? a queued list? a matrix? a class? why does the length of the items vary, and why do you want to compare different subitems? Try using classes and override `__cmp__`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the code is a good deal longer than what I posted up and that is about the best format I could get it into. It's just this one section that acts on it in some strange ways. Anyway, I appreciate you answering.